# Why does charge move at a constant velocity throughout a circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits

If there was a resistor, the charge carriers before the resistor hasn't been slowed down by the resistor yet, so I would've thought they'd be moving faster than the charge carriers after the resistor. And when the charge carriers finally do reach the end of the circuit, what happens then? Do the charge carriers cross the cell? If that happens, then how can it get from one side to the other (as electrons are negatively charged, so will get repelled by the negative terminal.)

Comment: Nitpick: you mean constant _current_. This is roughly the same as constant (drift) speed if the wires have constant cross section and constant (drift) velocity if the wires are all perfectly straight.

Comment: see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/miccur.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A circuit is, by definition, a closed loop of charges. If any charges were to accelerate, then there would be overdensity of charge in one section of the circuit over another (unless they were all accelerating together, but then eventually they would need to stop after reaching some maximum velocity). That overdensity would be attracted to the underdensity and the charges would naturally even out. You can imagine how magnets on a hoop would even themselves out in distance, electrons do the same with velocity.

Comment: And if the wire narrows in a small section of the circuit?

Comment: Then any slowing would cause a slight bunch up of electrons, which would increase the forces between them, speeding them up exactly to counteract it and the charge density per unit length remains constant.

Comment: Precisely.  In other words, the velocity is not necessarily constant throughout the circuit.